# Intro Animations

Tags: language-agnostic

Assuming I am correct, how do I convince my client that those annoying intro animations you're sometimes subjected to are harmful and not appealing to visitors?  I know I personally always click on "skip intro" and I feel this is one of those novelties that is dated.

His site is to showcase his services which are manufacturing related.  What I'm saying is this is not an entertainment website for kids or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned a lot about web usability from [Jakob Nielsen](http://www.useit.com/). This is from 10 years ago, but it still applies in 2010:

[Flash: 99% Bad](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20001029.html)

> Splash pages were an early sin of
>   abusive Web design. Luckily, almost
>   all professional websites have removed
>   this usability barrier. However, we're
>   now seeing the rise of Flash intros
>   that have the same obnoxious effect:
>   They delay users' ability to get what
>   they came for.

Answer (score 3):

Use a tool like google analytics to find out the average length of time on the intro page, if its less than the time it takes to watch the intro then it becomes clear that most people just skip the intro.

Of course you would either need the site live or another similar site to do the research first.

Comment: Good idea.  Like you pointed out, I'd have to first create the bad site to collect evidence.  I'd rather rely on someone else's research.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind putting a bit of effort, I would suggest you create an intro for your client. As denial can lead to an unsatisfied customer.

So better do what they ask for.....I believe a flash intro for manufacturing sector won't be that hard. Later you can let them know how much time someone coming from outside can take to reach particular info....on the website. let the client draw his own conclusions.